# Spring security and ldap

Tags: authentication, ldap, spring-security

this is my first time trying spring security and ldap. I have couple of novice questions. My main confusions are:

1. How do we assign roles to users? Is it done on ldap server? or done via a configuration file in my webapp? By roles I mean, Couple of users would have all the access to webapp features(Admins), Regular users (Read only access to webapp data), Analytic group (Users which can run a report in webapp)
2. Currently application uses `j_security_check` for normal user authentication with ldap server. (Where is Websphere do we hook up ldap connection settings for this authentication?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it confusing too, and developed my own module which ties in with Java EE Security.

Basically the webapp is set up with standard Java EE Security, and methods on spring beans can be given the `@RolesAllowed` annotation, in which case the logged in user's roles are checked against the required roles just before calling the method. [See here for details](http://blog.maxant.co.uk/pebble/2009/06/02/1243967400000.html).

You can use LDAP or a database or a file - where the roles and users are stored is up to you.  Normally for production, you will use LDAP or a connector to some kind of directory server.  Sorry I can't help with WebSphere - been a while since I set it up for security.

Comment: Hi Ant, thanks for the reply. you at least cleared some of my doubts. So we can say that "Roles can only be defined either on ldap server/DB Table/File", right? So implementing it via ldap would definitely involve ldap administrators as well. Developer cant implement all this on its own.

Comment: You need someone with LDAP admin skills for setting up and managing the users and their roles in LDAP.  Then you need a WebSphere admin who knows how to set up the an LDAP Realm in Websphere and map it to your application.  Then you need a Spring Developer who knows ACEGI (or whatever it is these days), OR, you get a simple Java developer to use my quick and dirty library ;-)

Comment: I guess I'll play around with Acegi(Spring Security 3 these days) but definitely need LDAP Admin and Websphere admins. This helped me a lot. I didnt know where to begin for this :D